# No dependency satisfies type interface org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService

Tags: neo4j

We wanted to upgrade our neo4J cluster from neo4J 3.4.x to neo4J 3.5.2, but now we are facing with the following problem:

```
2019-01-28 08:52:41.894+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@72dc9f9d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "No dependency satisfies type interface org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService". Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@72dc9f9d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "No dependency satisfies type interface org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService".
    org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@72dc9f9d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "No dependency satisfies type interface org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService".
            at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:45)
            at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:184)
            at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:123)
            at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:90)
            at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.CommercialEntryPoint.main(CommercialEntryPoint.java:22)
    Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@72dc9f9d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "No dependency satisfies type interface org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService".
            at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:473)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
            at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:177)
            ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases
            at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:216)
            at com.neo4j.commercial.edition.CommercialGraphDatabase.<init>(CommercialGraphDatabase.java:20)
            at com.neo4j.server.database.CommercialGraphFactory.newGraphDatabase(CommercialGraphFactory.java:40)
            at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:78)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
            ... 5 more
            Suppressed: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'com.sila.neo4j.transaction.RegisterTransactionEventHandlerExtensionFactory$1@5e1d6ace' failed to transition from stopped to shutting_down. Please see the attached cause exception "No dependency satisfies type interface org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService".
                    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:526)
                    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:185)
                    at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.AbstractKernelExtensions.shutdown(AbstractKernelExtensions.java:94)
                    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:518)
                    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:185)
                    at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.spi.ClassicCoreSPI.shutdown(ClassicCoreSPI.java:171)
                    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.shutdown(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:357)
                    at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:224)
                    ... 9 more
            Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: No dependency satisfies type interface org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService
                    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Dependencies.resolveDependency(Dependencies.java:66)
                    at org.neo4j.graphdb.DependencyResolver$Adapter.resolveDependency(DependencyResolver.java:145)
                    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.DependenciesProxy$ProxyHandler.invoke(DependenciesProxy.java:80)
                    at com.sila.neo4j.transaction.$Proxy24.getGraphDatabaseService(Unknown Source)
                    at com.sila.neo4j.transaction.RegisterTransactionEventHandlerExtensionFactory$1.shutdown(RegisterTransactionEventHandlerExtensionFactory.java:34)
                    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:518)
                    ... 16 more
    Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'com.sila.neo4j.transaction.RegisterTransactionEventHandlerExtensionFactory$1@5e1d6ace' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "No dependency satisfies type interface org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService".
            at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:473)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.AbstractKernelExtensions.start(AbstractKernelExtensions.java:82)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
            at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:211)
            ... 9 more
    Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: No dependency satisfies type interface org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Dependencies.resolveDependency(Dependencies.java:66)
            at org.neo4j.graphdb.DependencyResolver$Adapter.resolveDependency(DependencyResolver.java:145)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.DependenciesProxy$ProxyHandler.invoke(DependenciesProxy.java:80)
            at com.sila.neo4j.transaction.$Proxy24.getGraphDatabaseService(Unknown Source)
            at com.sila.neo4j.transaction.RegisterTransactionEventHandlerExtensionFactory$1.start(RegisterTransactionEventHandlerExtensionFactory.java:26)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
            ... 14 more
```

Here is the snippet of the code:

```
public class RegisterTransactionEventHandlerExtensionFactory extends KernelExtensionFactory<RegisterTransactionEventHandlerExtensionFactory.Dependencies> {

    @Override
    public Lifecycle newInstance(KernelContext kernelContext, final Dependencies dependencies) throws Throwable {
        return new LifecycleAdapter() {

            private SilaTransactionEventHandler handler;
            private ExecutorService executor;

            @Override
            public void start() throws Throwable {
                executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
                handler = new SilaTransactionEventHandler(dependencies.getGraphDatabaseService(), executor);
                dependencies.getGraphDatabaseService().registerTransactionEventHandler(handler);
            }

            @Override
            public void shutdown() throws Throwable {
                executor.shutdown();
                dependencies.getGraphDatabaseService().unregisterTransactionEventHandler(handler);
            }
        };
    }

    interface Dependencies {
        GraphDatabaseService getGraphDatabaseService();
    }

    public RegisterTransactionEventHandlerExtensionFactory() {
        super("registerTransactionEventHandler");
    }

}
```

There was no problem with neo4J 3.4.x, so there must me definitely some change in the the latest version. Does anyone has the same problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution which I got from neo4J community forum:

https://community.neo4j.com/t/no-dependency-satisfies-type-interface-org-neo4j-graphdb-graphdatabaseservice/4682

The only change which I had to do:

```
public RegisterTransactionEventHandlerExtensionFactory() {
    super(ExtensionType.DATABASE, "registerTransactionEventHandler");
}
```